Jdk8 compiled code on jdk21 environment using Java - the correct jar running Java. Lang. NoClassDefFoundError
Jdk8 compiled code on jdk21 environment using Java - the correct jar running Java. Lang. NoClassDefFoundError: Java/SQL/Driver。
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/Driver
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
at com.thunisoft.tas.server.util.ClosableClassLoader.defineClass(ClosableClassLoader.java:105)
at com.thunisoft.tas.server.util.ClosableClassLoader.findClass(ClosableClassLoader.java:52)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
at com.thunisoft.tas.server.module.jdbc.JdbcService.injectDriver(JdbcService.java:628)
at com.thunisoft.tas.server.module.jdbc.JdbcService.doStart(JdbcService.java:83)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:384)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:313)
at com.thunisoft.tas.server.TasManager.doStart(TasManager.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:1931)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:571)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1881)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:218)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:491)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
at com.thunisoft.tas.start.TasServiceWrapperListener.doStart(TasServiceWrapperListener.java:71)
at com.thunisoft.tas.start.TasServiceWrapperListener.access$000(TasServiceWrapperListener.java:15)
at com.thunisoft.tas.start.TasServiceWrapperListener$1.run(TasServiceWrapperListener.java:46)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.sql.Driver
at com.thunisoft.tas.server.util.ClosableClassLoader.findClass(ClosableClassLoader.java:57)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 34 common frames omitted

You probably are running your application as a module, but did not include the java.sql module in your module descriptor.

Format your posted error properly. Post all of it, not ….

There’s a custom class loader involved (ClosableClassLoader). So I guess, this custom class loader has the bootstrap class loader as its parent loader, but java.sql.Driver will be loaded by the platform class loader in JDK 21. As a side note, the name “ClosableClassLoader” suggests that this code is reinventing the wheel, as URLClassLoader is Closeable since Java 7, so if that’s the main feature of the class loader, you don’t need a custom class loader.
